# Creating login animation like facebook android

Tags: android, animation

I want to create a login page (Like facebook android app) where the userid and password `EditText` fields are hidden. A logo is shown on the page which animates above upto a certain distance and stays at the new position and then the edit fields are shown.

Here is something I have tried. But here the logo starts from bottom of the page and travels to the top of the page. Where as I want the logo to start from middle of the page and shift a little up to its new position.

Any idea on how this can be done>?

main.xml

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

res/anim/animationfile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<translate
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromYDelta="50%p"
    android:toYDelta="-50%p" 
   />
     </set>
```

Main.java

```
  Animation translatebu= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animationfile);
       // tv.setText("Some text view.");
        img.startAnimation(translatebu);
```

---

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1st The facebook image goes up so you have to translate it from current position to top

```
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="-30%p"
    android:duration="1000" />
```

Here `android:fromYDelta` is start position and `android:toYDelta` is end position in percentage i.e `-30%` and `android:duration` is in time i.e. 1 second

2nd Now attach a listener to check when animation is done
3rd Now Fade in your login box

here is the code

**MinActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button startAnimation =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final LinearLayout LoginBox = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LoginBox);
        LoginBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        startAnimation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Animation animTranslate  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.translate);
                animTranslate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) { }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) { }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                        LoginBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Animation animFade  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade);
                        LoginBox.startAnimation(animFade);
                    }
                });
                ImageView imgLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imgLogo.startAnimation(animTranslate);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

And in the `anim` folder use these xml's

**fade.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" >
    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

**translate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="-30%p"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

And the layout
**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Start Animation" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LoginBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email ID" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That works great, but if I open the soft keyboard with WindowSoftInputMode = AdjustResize, then the image is lost (because it is translated outside of the window). Do you know how to prevent that?

Comment: Well the window resizes to fit it, so you would have t find the keyboard height and place elements based on screen height, elements placed inside etc. However this would have to be done gracefully else it will spoil the beauty so it upto on how you handle the resize

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move whole layout up at the time of soft keyword appears then just add this in your corresponding Activity in manifest file. `"android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`