# Animate an ImageView that is centered horizontally and vertically

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an ImageView that is centered horizontally and vertically, and I need to create an animation with this ImageView moving up.

How can I do this?

I have the following code:

Xml

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image_logo_splash"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java

```
        Animation logoAnimation = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            final ImageView logoImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_logo_splash);
            final float newTopMargin = 20;

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.topMargin = (int)(newTopMargin * interpolatedTime);
            logoImage.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    };

    ImageView logoImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_logo_splash);
    logoImage.startAnimation(logoAnimation);
```

Comment: Can you please explain it in detail, I mean what you want exactly??

Comment: I have an Splash activity that displays the app logo centered in the screen, I need to animate it moving to the top of the screen, so other content can be displayed in the bottom of the screen after animation ends.

Comment: and your code does not work? what are the symptops?

Comment: The image is not moving.

Comment: have you implement any animation code on it.

Comment: try adding some Log.d and see what are the margins

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52394/animation-discussion join here juliano

Comment: have a look at [this](https://github.com/hearbeathorror/Animating-View-Translate), it will help!!

Comment: Just try below link, it may be useful to you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672022/creating-login-animation-like-facebook-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st The facebook image goes up so you have to translate it from current position to top

```
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="-30%p"
    android:duration="1000" />
```

Here android:fromYDelta is start position and android:toYDelta is end position in percentage i.e -30% and android:duration is in time i.e. 1 second

2nd Now attach a listener to check when animation is done 3rd Now Fade in your login box

here is the code

MinActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button startAnimation =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final LinearLayout LoginBox = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LoginBox);
        LoginBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        startAnimation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Animation animTranslate  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.translate);
                animTranslate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) { }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) { }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                        LoginBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Animation animFade  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade);
                        LoginBox.startAnimation(animFade);
                    }
                });
                ImageView imgLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imgLogo.startAnimation(animTranslate);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

And in the anim folder use these xml's

fade.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" >
    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

translate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="-30%p"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

And the layout activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Start Animation" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LoginBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```